# Is there a way to determine a member offset at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm finding I'm spending a lot of time trying to determine member offsets of structures while debugging.  I was wondering if there was a quick way to determine the offset of a member within a large structure at compile time.  (Note: I know several ways of creating compile time assertions that an offset is in a given range, and I can do a binary search for the correct value, but I'm looking for something more efficient).  I'm using a fairly recent version of `gcc` to compile *C* code.

Comment: macro `offsetof(structure, fieldname)` doesn't help?

Comment: @MarianV Why not make that an answer (perhaps with an example of usage)?

Comment: @eric_finn OK. I am not sure if it works at compile time.

Comment: What do you mean by "at compile time"? The compiler is required to be able to determine that `offsetof` results in a constant expression (e.g. you can use it for the size of a static-storage array); this is the closest thing to a formal definition of "at compile-time" you can get. The only other possible meaning is "usable in preprocessor `#if` conditionals; this of course is not possible with `offsetof` since the preprocessor has no knowledge of structures.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I didn't explain this as well as I thought...  I was looking for a method of determining the offset _without_ actually running the code.  Loading and running the system takes a long time, and I often do not have access to the system I'm debugging.  I tried declaring an array like this:  `char dbg[0-sizeof(offsetof(x,y)];`, which causes the compile to fail, but does not print out the actual offset.  I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible, but I thought I'd throw it out there in case it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question here:  Note: I'm looking to determine the offset at *compile time*, that is, I don't want to have to run the code (I can also compile just the files I need, and not the whole system):  The following can be cut and paste for those who are interested:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#define offsetof_ct(structname, membername) \
void ___offset_##membername ## ___(void) { \
        volatile char dummy[10000 + offsetof(structname, membername) ]; \
        dummy[0]=dummy[0]; \
}

struct x {
        int a[100];
        int b[20];
        int c[30];
};

offsetof_ct(struct x,a);
offsetof_ct(struct x,b);
offsetof_ct(struct x,c);
```

And then run:

```
~/tmp> gcc tst.c -Wframe-larger-than=1000
tst.c: In function â€˜___offset_a___â€™:
tst.c:16:1: warning: the frame size of 10000 bytes is larger than 1000 bytes
tst.c: In function â€˜___offset_b___â€™:
tst.c:17:1: warning: the frame size of 10400 bytes is larger than 1000 bytes
tst.c: In function â€˜___offset_c___â€™:
tst.c:18:1: warning: the frame size of 10480 bytes is larger than 1000 bytes
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I then subtract 10000 to get the offset.  Note: I tried adding `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wframe-larger-than=1000"` into the file, but it didn't like it, so it'll have to be specified on the command line.

John

Answer (score 7):

[offsetof](http://linux.die.net/man/3/offsetof) is what you want for this and it compile time. The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.17` *Common definitions* paragraph *3* says:

> offsetof(type, member-designator)
>
> > which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of
> >     which is the offset in bytes [...]

the man pages linked above has the following sample code, which demonstrates it's usage:

```
struct s {
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;
    char a[];
};

/* Output is compiler dependent */

printf("offsets: i=%ld; c=%ld; d=%ld a=%ld\n",
        (long) offsetof(struct s, i),
        (long) offsetof(struct s, c),
        (long) offsetof(struct s, d),
        (long) offsetof(struct s, a));
printf("sizeof(struct s)=%ld\n", (long) sizeof(struct s));
```

sample output, which may vary:

```
 offsets: i=0; c=4; d=8 a=16
 sizeof(struct s)=16
```

For reference *constant expressions* are covered in section `6.6` *Constant expressions* and paragraph *2* says:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and
>   accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

**Update**

After clarification from the OP I came up with a new methods using `-O0 -fverbose-asm  -S` and *grep*, code is as follows:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct s {
        int i;
        char c;
        double d;
        char a[];
    };

int main()
{
    int offsetArray[4] = { offsetof(struct s, i ), offsetof( struct s, c ), offsetof(struct s, d ), offsetof(struct s, a )  } ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

build using:

```
gcc -x c -std=c99 -O0 -fverbose-asm  -S main.cpp && cat main.s | grep offsetArray
```

sample output (*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faaa8ca8463eeda7)*):

```
movl    $0, -16(%rbp)   #, offsetArray
movl    $4, -12(%rbp)   #, offsetArray
movl    $8, -8(%rbp)    #, offsetArray
movl    $16, -4(%rbp)   #, offsetArray
```

Comment: Just to make it clear to the OP, since he obviously never heard about this: Here's an example usage for a structure `mystruct` to which you want to know the offset of member `x`: `offsetof(struct mystruct, x);`

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of offsetof, however it doesn't fit my needs, as I do not know a way of outputting the value at compile time.  This is a remote (embedded) system I'm debugging, and while I have crash logs, I don't have ready access to the system itself.

Comment: @John going off of you comment in the main question and following my example above you could do this `int arr[4] = { offsetof(struct s, i ), offsetof( struct s, c ), offsetof(struct s, d ), offsetof(struct s, a )  } ;` ... If that is not sufficient then you will need to flesh out the details a bit more perhaps with some code to clarify.

Comment: Interesting -- I suppose I could do an objdump of the array, and print the values that way.  I think I've stumbled upon something else though -- if you fail compilation due to an oversized stack, the compiler tells you what the stack size was...  I am just trying it out now.

Comment: @John ok, you can use `-O0 -fverbose-asm  -S` and you can then use grep, I will add to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
#define OFFSETOF(T, m) \
  (size_t) (((char *) &(((T*) NULL)->m)) - ((char *) ((T*) NULL)))
```

Call it like this:

```
size_t off = OFFSETOF(struct s, c);
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `offsetof` is standard, and is defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Just to show how this could be achieved, if you're alone in the woods.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think this is debatable but it could be argued and many have that all the common offsetof macros are not well defined unless they are part of the implementation.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make any sense. If you have a conforming C implementation, you have `offsetof`. Your `OFFSETOF` macro, though it may work, exhibits undefined behavior. (A particular `offsetof` implementation likely does so as well, but it has to work for the particular implementation.) Unless you're writing your own `<stddef.h>`, there's not much point.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Exactly.